# Concatenating Files - Including files in folders

Tags: file, ant, command-line, batch-file, concatenation

I currently have this command:

```
copy /b *.txt newfile.txt
```

But I want to include all files with folders as well.

How can I do this? Is it possible to add this to Apache Ant as well?
I also consider doing this to minify JS files.

Im using windows and would like a command to run or batch file but having issues.

Is there anyway to remove lines as well?
Is there a better command to use than the one I am currently using?

UPDATE:

```
<target name="concatenate" description="Concatenate all js files">
    <concat destfile="build/application.js">
        <fileset dir="js" includes="*.js" />
    </concat>
</target>
<target name="compress" depends="concatenate" description="Compress application.js to application-min.js">
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false">
        <filelist dir="build" files="application.js" />
        <arg line="-jar" />
        <arg path="C:\yuicompressor-2.4.7\build\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg line="-o" />
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="build/*-min.js" />
        <targetfile />
    </apply>
```

Now i am using the above code but cant get it to include files within folders

Comment: [ant concat will do the job of concatenating](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html)

Comment: `includes="**/*.js"`  the `**/` part is ant way of including subfolders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [oers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644450/oers) pointed out in the comment, Ant patterns use `**` to recursively match directories. Here is the relevant [Patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#Patterns) section from the Ant manual:

> To make things a bit more flexible, we add one extra feature, which makes it possible to match multiple directory levels. This can be used to match a complete directory tree, or a file anywhere in the directory tree. To do this, `**` must be used as the name of a directory. When `**` is used as the name of a directory in the pattern, it matches zero or more directories. For example: `/test/**` matches all files/directories under `/test/,` such as `/test/x.java,` or `/test/foo/bar/xyz.html,` but not `/xyz.xml`.
>
> There is one "shorthand": if a pattern ends with `/` or `\`, then `**` is appended. For example, `mypackage/test/` is interpreted as if it were `mypackage/test/**`.

The "concatenate" target above would be:

```
<target name="concatenate" description="Concatenate all js files">
  <concat destfile="build/application.js">
    <fileset dir="js" includes="**/*.js" excludes="**/*.min.js" />
  </concat>
</target>
```

Comment: Very good answer, if i wanted to excluse files such as .min.js but allow .js how would i do this?

Comment: Is there a way to do this but in a certain order?

Comment: @LiamMcCann, see updated answer showing how to exclude files ending in `*.min.js`.